# facebook Graph API Send post using asp.net and c# is not working

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, post, facebook-graph-api

I want to send post through asp.net and c# to my facebook account,i tried multiple things but unable to understand why it is giving me error, can any one guide me?

**My App Details**

```
private const string FacebookApiId = "XXXXXX";
private const string FacebookApiSecret = "XXXXXX";
private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat =
            "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
     string accessToken = GetAccessToken(FacebookApiId, FacebookApiSecret);
     PostMessage(accessToken, "My message");
     return View();
}
```

**My Api Details**

```
static void PostMessage(string accessToken, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
                dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
                messagePost.access_token = accessToken;
                messagePost.message = message;
            var result = facebookClient.Post("/798252384337611/feed", messagePost);
            }
            catch (FacebookOAuthException ex)
            {
                string error = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string error1 = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
        static string GetAccessToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
        {
            string accessToken = string.Empty;
            string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Fbresponse rs = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fbresponse>(responseString);
                accessToken = rs.access_token;
            }
            if (accessToken.Trim().Length == 0)
                throw new Exception("There is no Access Token");
            return accessToken;
        }
```

**My Tries**

```
 1 -   var result = facebookClient.Post("/me/feed", messagePost);
```

**Error**

(OAuthException - #2500) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

```
2 - var result = facebookClient.Post("/rashid.khi.31/feed", messagePost);
```

**Error**

(OAuthException - #803) (#803) Cannot query users by their username (rashid.khi.31)

As my RND on google then i got fb User ID from fb Username on https://findmyfbid.in/

```
3 - var result = facebookClient.Post("/100055422049992/feed", messagePost);
```

**Error**

(OAuthException - #100) (#100) The global id 100055422049992 is not allowed for this call

Please help me what wrong with my code or some thing else, I know, I am sending wrong user_id but i dont't know from where i can get correct id ?

Comment: You are going to need to poor over the Facebook Developer docs for this one. Or find a Facebook Developer discussion forum to join. As you are getting back an error message from Facebook, then your code is working. You are just not sending them the right data. And to figure out why is something nobody here will be able to help you with.

Comment: You need to use an app scoped user ID. You get that back when the user logs in.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston the Facebook Developer discussion forum is not good,i post my question still no one respond. I saw people are not responding on fb forum.

Comment: @WizKid i generate user access token and scoped id from Facebook tools now i am receiving "sucess : true" but i am unable to see my post on my timeline, any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick note - the code you came up with is VERY old. `offline_access` permission was removed years ago. So I would suggest you do more googling on how to create tokens. Perhaps your token is simply invalid.

I found this link: https://ermir.net/article/how-to-publish-a-message-to-a-facebook-page-using-a-dotnet-console-application - it shows how to get permanent token from FB Debug page, and then how to use it to post to the page (which looks similar to your code):

```
public class FacebookApi
{
    private readonly string FB_PAGE_ID;
    private readonly string FB_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    private const string FB_BASE_ADDRESS = "https://graph.facebook.com/";

    public FacebookApi(string pageId, string accessToken)
    {
        FB_PAGE_ID = pageId;
        FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = accessToken;
    }

    public async Task<string> PublishMessage(string message)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(FB_BASE_ADDRESS);

            var parametters = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "access_token", FB_ACCESS_TOKEN },
                { "message", message }
            };
            var encodedContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parametters);

            var result = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{FB_PAGE_ID}/feed", encodedContent);
            var msg = result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

    }
}
```

So try to hardcode the token from FB Debug page first and see if you can publish. Then work on obtaining short-lived token from inside your app - but that would require user to be able to communicate with Facebook - to allow YOUR app to communicate with THEIR page. Makes sense?